# Is there a film or series called Star Wars: Tales of the Jedi being developed?

Tags: star-wars

Reference what is purported to be the [2021 Christmas gift by Lucasfilm, Ltd.](https://m.imgur.com/gallery/XCnFpfv) to Lucasfilm employees:
a record player with carrying case.

The carrying case includes icons of brand logos on its sides.

One side includes four upcoming films or series:

- Indians Jones 5
- The Book of Boba Fett
- Andor
- Obi-Wan
  [image: Indy5, Fett, Andur, Obi1]

The other side includes another four:

- Willow
- Bad Batch
- Tales of the Jedi
- Visions
  [image: TOTJ WTF]

Of the projects listed on this side, *Willow* is a future series in production for 2022 release, and both *The Bad Batch* and *Visions* are already existing series, with future works of *Bad Batch* already being planned.

Of the eight listed projects, just a single one, *Tales of the Jedi*, has had no reported series developed or in development.

Is *Star Wars: Tales of the Jedi* branded series or film being developed by LFL?

Comment: Do Jedi even _have_ tails?

Comment: there's no official word yet that Visions will have a season 2

Comment: Lol! “Opinion-based” question?

Comment: since there is no official word one way or another, what could the answer possibly be? Right now the only reason the question is being asked is because of speculation over leaked image of a logo on an internal company christmas present box. What else could an answer be at this point other than opinion? :)

Comment: https://www.starwarsnewsnet.com/2021/12/lucasfilm-holiday-gift-lists-star-wars-tales-of-the-jedi-and-visions-alongside-other-upcoming-movies-and-series.html - No official word, as yet.

Comment: The “opinion” choice rationale is stupid; how can the question possibly be “Update{d} so it can be answered with facts and citations?” The answer is the fact of either yes or no as reasonably supported by authoritative infornation, or a bad answer if not one of those.

Comment: Interesting, _Monsters at Work_ animation studio has been ramping up production on new LFL animated project.